# Cannot call an abstract member

Tags: c#

I am doing my homework in C# in which I dealing with abstract class.

```
public abstract class Account
{   
    public abstract bool Credit(double amount); 
    public abstract bool Debit(double amount);
}

public class SavingAccount : Account
{
    public override bool Credit(double amount)
    {
        bool temp = true;   
        temp = base.Credit(amount + calculateInterest());  
        return temp;  
    }

    public override bool Debit(double amount)
    {
        bool flag = true;    
        double temp = getBalance();    
        temp = temp - amount;

        if (temp < 10000)
        {
            flag = false;
        }

        else
        {
            return (base.Debit(amount));
        }

        return flag;
    }
}
```

When I call the base.Debit() or base.Credit() then it gives me an error `cannot call an abstract base member`.

Comment: What is the question? what are you trying to accomplish? do you understand what abstract means?

Comment: What would you expect it to do? It's *abstract*, it doesn't do anything, so you can't call it.

Comment: Calla `this.Debit()` instead of `Base` and it should work :)

Comment: My question is why I am facing the error? there is syntax error or my concept error.

Comment: You can't call `base` in a derived class if base is abstract (in this case, `base` is Account).  Simply remove your `else` statement.

Comment: Let's say that calling base.Credit() is baseless.  You explicitly said "I refuse to implement basic crediting".  Compiler says "okay, then what the heck do you want me to do then?"  Not syntax, it is concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call abstract methods, the idea is that a method declared abstract simply requires derived classes to define it. Using `base.Debit` is in affect trying to call an abstract method, which cannot be done. Reading your code more closely, I think this is what you wanted for `Debit()`

```
public abstract class Account
{
  protected double _balance;

  public abstract bool Credit(double amount);
  public abstract bool Debit(double amount);
}

public class SavingAccount : Account
{
  public double MinimumBalance { get; set; }

  public override bool Debit(double amount)
  {
    if (amount < 0)
      return Credit(-amount);

    double temp = _balance;
    temp = temp - amount;

    if (temp < MinimumBalance)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      _balance = temp;
      return true;
    }
  }

  public override bool Credit(double amount)
  {
    if (amount < 0)
      return Debit(-amount);

    _balance += amount;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Abstract means there is no implementation. You use it to force the derived class to provide there own. Therefore you should not be calling an abstract method directly. I recommend reading this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.80).aspx