# Create an object through a reference of an object

Tags: c#

I am doing homework in C# in which I am implementing the abstract class of Account then I derived two classes form Account named as Saving Account and Checking Account and override some methods in derived classes. Now my problem statement says

Only Instantiate SavingAccount and CheckingAccount Through a reference of Account

Now I am unable to write the code of this because I know the simple object creation but I don't know how to create an object through the reference of an object. Please tell me some syntax. Thanx

Comment: Are these guys in the same class? hehe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218686/cannot-call-an-abstract-member/10218831#10218831

Comment: I think what payo has said is what your assignment is looking for. The wording in your description is somewhat strange, however. Is the sentence "Only Instantiate SavingAccount and CheckingAccount Through a reference of Account" a literal quote from the assignment or have you paraphrased?

Comment: :) well, I didn't take the time to read the entire user name, go ahead and make an account name in stack overflow with a recognizable name.

Comment: @Thomas I bet it is verbatim. That is an awful way to say it imo.

Comment: @Thomas This is what confused me and made me forget that `Account` is specified to be abstract. It seems ambiguous, I think it could be taken to mean create a derived type from a base type.

Comment: If it is verbatim from the homework than post the school name. Knowing what school gives this would be useful for other people to avoid it :) (Also I somewhat doubt as there are way to many capital letters in the sentence "Only Instantiate SavingAccount and CheckingAccount Through a reference of Account").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is that an identifier can be the base type:

```
SomeBaseType identifier;
```

But when you instantiate it (or new up an instance), you can use any derived type

e.g.

```
Account account = new SavingsAccount();
```

**EDIT** I wanted to add that this is where OOP comes to life (read: "gets really fun!"). Now you can design an `interface` or contract (such as with an `Account` class) - and program to the one design. But you may have different account types *actually* used. With the example I gave, `account` will continue to look like an `Account`. Any 'new' methods or features in `SavingsAccount` will not be immediately visiable to code using your `account` variable. But that's okay! You don't want your code to be specifically tailored to `SavingsAccount` (in MOST cases), you want to instead design a flexible `Account` that can represent the basic and common features of any `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a SavingAccount or CheckingAccount from an instance of Account that you already have then you can cast it `as` one of those accounts. Like so -

```
int _accountID = 356;
Account _account = new SavingsAccount(_accountID);

// now to create a SavingAccount or CheckingAccount from _account

SavingAccount _savingAccount = _account as SavingAccount;
```

Comment: According to the description Account is abstract. You can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for pointing that out. I was being absent minded :) (it's getting late in the UK).